# How to style the DIV to display html controls

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="dispLoginSearch" style="text-align: left; overflow: hidden;"> <!-- LOGIN AND SEARCH -->
    <div class="theLoginBox" style="clear: both;">
        <div class="loginTitle">
            Log in to <span style="font-family: 'blackjarregular'; font-size: 14pt; color: #FE7816;">My</span> <span style="font-family: 'trajanpro'; font-size: 12pt; color: #00529B;">WD</span> | Sign Up
            <br />
            <input type="text" value="Username" /> <input type="password" value="Password" /> <input type="button" value="Go" />
            <br />
            <span style="float: right;">Forgot login/password</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="z-index: 99999999999;">
        <input type="text" value="Search WD" />
    </div>
</div> <!-- LOGIN AND SEARCH -->
```

CSS:

```
.dispLoginSearch
{
    width: 47%;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #0026ff;
}
.theLoginBox
{
    border: 2px solid #D5D5D5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 97%;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #ff6a00;
}
.loginTitle
{
    height: 88px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    background: #b6ff00;
}
```

When I view the website, I see the following:

[image]

What I would like it be shown:

[image]

How do I fix the issue? It is happening in both IE and other browsers.

UPDATE:

I added `overflow: auto` in the `loginTitle` class and this is what is shown:

[image]

Each section is taking up a lot of space and showing the scrollbar :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2mpv131u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of `line 5` of your CSS : `line-height: 150px;`.

Just remove it and you should be fine.

Comment: I copied the code put it somewhere else on the page and it is fine. Can I add my entire CSS for the header?

Comment: Did you try to remove `line-height: 150px;` ? Did it solve your problem? If not, please explain in detail what the problem is :)

Comment: I had a line height to the parent DIV to 160px which was causing the issue. THANK YOU :)

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't forget to mark the answer if your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to look like image you attached, see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FothH

html:

```
<form action="#">
  <p>Log in to ###### | Sign up</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
  <a href="#">Forgot login/password</a>
</form>
```

css:

```
form {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  display: block;
  width: 375px;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}

form p {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 35px;

}

input {
  display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 7px;

}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  border: none;
  background: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  width: 180px;
}

input[type=password] {
  width: 120px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 25px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  background: none;
  color: red;
  border: none;
}

form a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: The thing is my code works if I move it elsewhere. It is just within that piece of code that it is messed up.

Comment: I just changed the FORM to SPAN and have it working. Wonder what was causing my issue :/

Comment: I also want to add a SEARCH box right underneath it. How can I add that?

Comment: add another form and style it accordingly. also be careful, if you change FORM to SPAN, it may not work as proper form. and SPAN is meant to be used for inline elements, such as text, or etc (it won't give you any validation errors though, just semantically it's rather incorrect).